# How can I tell if a iPhone binary has been compiled as a Position Independent Executable

Tags: ios, xcode4.3, xcodebuild

I have an automated build process which compiles a iPhone app using a combination of xcodebuild and xcrun. When the build calls xcodebuild it passes in a xcconfig file which overrides certain settings.

`IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 4.3`

`ARCHS = armv7`

`VALID_ARCHS = armv7`

`LD_NO_PIE = NO`

In theory this should ensure that the binary output from the build is a Position Independent Executable. Is there any way to examine the Binary to see if this is actually the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With "otool -vh" you can see the "PIE" flag:

```
$ otool -vh YourApp
YourApp:
Mach header
      magic cputype cpusubtype  caps    filetype ncmds sizeofcmds      flags
   MH_MAGIC     ARM         V7  0x00     EXECUTE    28       3532   NOUNDEFS DYLDLINK TWOLEVEL PIE
```